# TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, rspec2

I have the following code:

```
class ProfileLookup < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    ProfileLookup.select("DISTINCT category").map{|c| c.category}.each do |category|
      define_method("available_#{category.pluralize}".to_sym) do
        ProfileLookup.where(category: category).order(:value).all.collect{|g| g.value}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which basically contains a load of lookup data, split out by category.  The aim is to create a method for each category in the database.  Via Rails console, this code works as expected:

```
ruby-1.9.3@hub :002 > ProfileLookup.available_genders
  ProfileLookup Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "profile_lookups".* FROM "profile_lookups" WHERE "profile_lookups"."category" = 'gender' ORDER BY value
 => ["Female", "Male"]
```

However, my specs are failing.  The following spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ProfileLookup do

  its(:available_genders).should include("Male")
  its(:available_age_groups).should include("0-17")
  its(:available_interests).should include("Autos & Vehicles")
  its(:available_countries).should include("United States")

end
```

fails with:

```
Exception encountered: #<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module)>
backtrace:
/Users/fred/code/my_app/spec/models/profile_lookup_spec.rb:5:in `include'
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: show us the include-line. wherever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this doesn't work:

- Implicit subjects don't appear to work with static methods
- You need a context, or `it` block around your examples:

This code works:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ProfileLookup do

  it 'should know what lookups are available' do
    ProfileLookup.available_genders.should include("Male")
    ProfileLookup.available_age_groups.should include("0-17")
    ProfileLookup.available_interests.should include("Autos & Vehicles")
    ProfileLookup.available_countries.should include("United States")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your syntax for `its` is wrong, you should [use the block form](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/2.7.1/RSpec/Core/Subject/ClassMethods#its-instance_method):

```
its(:available_genders) { should include("Male") }
```

Secondly, when you `describe` a class, the subject you're matching is an *instance* of that class:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/implicit-subject:

> If the first argument to the outermost example group is a class, an instance of that class is exposed to each example via the subject() method.

You can be explicit about the subject and everything will work:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ProfileLookup do

  subject { ProfileLookup }

  its(:available_genders) { should include("Male") }
  its(:available_age_groups) { should include("0-17") }
  its(:available_interests) { should include("Autos & Vehicles") }
  its(:available_countries) { should include("United States") }

end
```

Comment: +1. There is even a described_class helper. So the subject could be something like subject { described_class }.

Answer (score 0):

The `include` method is usually used to include a Module into a Class (or another Module). Looks like they didn't overwrite `include` in the `describe` scope, only in the `it` scope.